# Unix - ksh test if multiple variables are 0

Tags: ksh, test

So basically I want to test if 3 variables are 0. If one of them is not it should report it. This is what I got:

```
        if [[ $result -ne 0 && $resultmax -ne 0 && $resultmin -ne 0 ]]
        then
            echo "There is something terribly wrong."
        fi
```

It does not work. Any idea where I messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test that **one** of these variables is not 0, then you need `||` operator. Not `&&`.

```
$ if [[ 1 -ne 0 && 0 -ne 0 && 0 -ne 0 ]] ; then echo "There is something terribly wrong.";  fi

$ if [[ 1 -ne 0 || 0 -ne 0 || 0 -ne 0 ]] ; then echo "There is something terribly wrong.";  fi
There is something terribly wrong.
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you are testing if all variables are not 0 to report error. Try:

```
if [[ $result -ne 0 || $resultmax -ne 0 || $resultmin -ne 0 ]]
then
    echo "There is something terribly wrong."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To test if any of the variables is not 0 use the or operator `||` (as already suggested):

```
if [[ $result -ne 0 || $resultmax -ne 0 || $resultmin -ne 0 ]]
then
    echo "There is something terribly wrong."
fi
```

Though, if you're doing numerical computation and are using `ksh` (or `bash`, or `zsh`) you might prefer to use this syntax for clarity:

```
if (( result != 0 || resultmax != 0 || resultmin != 0 ))
then
    printf "%s\n" "There is something terribly wrong."
fi
```